# How to send file to com1 port?

Tags: c#

I need to send file (text file) to com1 (RS-232)  port, how i can do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

First answer:

```
type file.txt > com1
```

**Edit** after spotting the `C#` tag 8-) I think this will work:

```
using System.IO;
...
File.Copy(@"c:\file.txt", "com1");
```

but I can't properly test it as I have nothing I can plug into my COM1 port.  8-)  It appears to work, in that it blocks rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Does that work?!?  That's WAY simpler than what I was about to post!  I love this place... You learn something new every day.

Comment: I haven't tested that, but I think it should work.  Windows has a bunch of "magic" files defined, com0 through com4 being some of them.  More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

Comment: The question has a C# tag (although it is not clear in the question itself!) :)

Comment: In that case he can use the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start static method to implement your solution.

Answer (score 2):

It could go like:

```
serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
// other settings ...
serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
serialPort1.Open();

using (System.IO.TextReader reader = System.IO.File.OpentText("file.txt"))
{ 
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       serialPort1.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```